# Installing hadoop issue

Tags: hadoop

I am following Joseph Adler instructions on how to install ( page 555 here - http:// it-e

books. info/book/1014/ ) Hadoop on my lubuntu.

I wrote in terminal:

```
wget http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u4.tar.gz
tar xvfz hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u4.tar.gz
```

and everything went fine, `.tar.gz` file was downloaded and then it was untarred.

But when I wrote

```
hadoop version
```

in the terminal, there appeared a message saying that there is no command hadoop.

Does anybody has an idea on what should I do to use (already) installed but (still) somehow invisible Hadoop?
Thanks for help!

Comment: `./hadoop version` You need to make sure it's in your PATH

Answer (score 1):

In Linux invoking a command without prefixing its path requires the location where the command resides should be present the environment variable PATH.

Here, For executing the command you got to specify either absolute or relative path of the command. Following can be used, replace  with the extracted location.

```
<EXTRACT_LOC_PATH>/hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u4/bin/hadoop version
```

If your present working directory is /hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u4/bin/ then `./hadoop version` would be sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you are getting `COMMAND NOT FOUND ERROR` the problem will be there in `.bashrc` file only. You might not have properly set the `JAVA_HOME`, `HADOOP_HOME` and `PATH` Variable. So check it out whether you have given proper path for all these 3 variables or not.